# avr-g++ error when NVIDIA jetson TX2 running Ubuntu connecting to Arduino board

Tags: arduino, ros, master-slave, platformio, nvidia-jetson

I am working on the autonomous driving system of a university-made Mars rover with ROS. I am trying to communicate NVIDIA jetson (master system) with Arduino (slave system) to control ESC that is connected with a motor with platformio through USB. However, after I finished inputting the command

```
platformio run --target upload
```

the following error shows:
[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hq2Rw.png)

I have tried all solutions online, but none of them work and everytime led me to restore the Jetson. So please help!

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You could add the Stack Trace directly, better than an image URL, since these can change.

Comment: sorry and thank you for your advice! Can you help, please?